# Laplace equation with Dirichlet-problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Let $B$ be the unit ball,

$ B:= \left\lbrace (x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2} :x^2+y^2<1 \right\rbrace.$

I want to find a $u:B\to\mathbb R$ that satisfies the following conditions:

- $\Delta u(x,y)=x^4+x^2+2x^2y^2+y^2+y^4 $,   for  $(x,y) \in B$
- $u(x,y)=2xy$, for $(x,y) \in \partial B$

The inhomogeneity in the first condition is confusing me. Can someone please provide an explanation of how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this equation is inhomogeneous, we would call it "Poisson's equation", not "Laplace's equation".

Given the geometry of the setup, I would suggest you work in polar coordinates, $(x, y) = (r\cos\phi, r\sin\phi)$. Switching to polar coordinates, the task is to find a $u(r, \phi)$ that satisfies the PDE
$$ \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \right) + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial \phi^2} = r^2 + r^4 \qquad \qquad (\text{for } r < 1),$$
subject to the boundary condition
$$ u = \sin 2\phi \qquad \qquad (\text{for } r = 1).$$

To find the general solution to our PDE, we can use the following facts.

**Fact 1:** The general solution to the *homogeneous* equation $\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \right) + \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial \phi^2} = 0$ is
$$ u = a_0 + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left( a_n \cos(n\phi) + b_n \sin(n\phi)\right)r^n. $$
You can derive this solution using separation of variables. You'll almost certainly be able to find the derivation in your notes or textbook.

**Fact 2:** The function
$$ u = \tfrac{1}{16}r^4 + \tfrac{1}{36}r^6$$
is one particular solution to the full inhomogeneous equation $\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \right) + \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial \phi^2} = r^2 + r^4$.
You can obtain this solution by inspection, and you can verify that it works by substituting it into the PDE.

Combining these two facts, we see that
$$ u = a_0 + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left( a_n \cos(n\phi) + b_n \sin(n\phi)\right)r^n + \tfrac{1}{16}r^4 + \tfrac{1}{36}r^6$$
is the general solution to our full inhomogeneous PDE.

It remains to apply our boundary condition to determine the coefficients $a_n$ and $b_n$. If you work through this, you should be able to show that
$$ a_0 = - \tfrac 1 {16} - \tfrac 1 {36}, \qquad b_2 = 1, $$
and that all the other $a_n$'s and $b_n$'s are zero.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. For the final solution I get: $u(r,\phi)=-\frac{13}{144} + r^2 \sin(2 \phi)$ and in cartesian coordinates $u(x,y)=-\frac{13}{144} +2 (x^2+y^2)^2 xy $ are these solutions true?

Comment: Not quite. You forgot the $\tfrac 1{16}r^4 + \tfrac 1{36}r^6$ terms in the solution.

Comment: Also, $r^2\sin 2\phi$ is equal to $2xy$.

Comment: Ok, thank you :)